# What is more appropriate: "weekly meet" or "weekly meeting"?

Tags: verbs, nouns

We as a group meet once a week, for which we want to create an invite. For that meeting invite, we are confused whether it should be called: "weekly meeting" or "weekly meet".

Comment: You "have a weekly meeting", meet is not a noun, while meeting is the gerund and is therefore a noun. Moreover, you say "to have something", where something is a noun.

Comment: I for one am appalled at the loss of the gerund, and the adjectival present participle, in modern English. People talk about *fry-pans* and *swim-shorts*. How inadequate!. No I would use *meeting*, and it is also an *invitation*. *Invite* belongs with *innit* and *dunnit*, in my book.

Comment: @MarganFR: *Meet* is most definitely a noun, and has been since 1830. You have *"track meets"* and *swim meets* and never *track meetings* or *swim meetings*. But *meeting* is probably the most appropriate noun for this sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what your event is for. The definition of meet, according to Dictionary.com, is "*an assembly, as of persons and hounds for a hunt or swimmers or runners for a race or series of races*" while the definition of meeting is "*an assembly or conference of persons for a specific purpose*". A meet is when a group of people come together to carry something out, while a meeting is when a group of people come together to discuss something. As your event appears to be one of discussion, "*weekly meeting*" would be more appropriate.

> meet. (n.d.). Dictionary.com Unabridged. Retrieved April 18, 2016 from Dictionary.com website http://www.dictionary.com/browse/meet
>
> meeting. (n.d.). Dictionary.com Unabridged. Retrieved April 18, 2016 from Dictionary.com website http://www.dictionary.com/browse/meeting